# How to write submit handler on bootstrap validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am trying to submit a form using AJAX after the form is validated by Bootstrap Validator. It is not working for some reason. How can I get it to work? And how can I do the confirmation box before submitting the form?

```js
$('#accountUpdateForm form').bootstrapValidator({
  femphasized texteedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {

      'firstName': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {},
        }
      },
      'lastName': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {},
        }
      },

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {  
      alert("Submit Handler");
      var frm = $('#accountUpdateForm');
      frm.submit(function(ev) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: frm.attr('action'),
          data: frm.serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('Changes saved');
          }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();        
      });    
    }    
});
```

Comment: Which library are you using? https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator or https://github.com/formvalidation/formvalidation?

Comment: I am using bootstrapvalidator.

Comment: formvalidation has better documentation and a similar syntax. If you don't mind making the switch, I'd recommend that.